# En Regresión Lineal con R, cuando una variable independiente es categórica, se la cambia a numérica. Puede hacerse cuando es la variable a predecir?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regresión-lineal, ciencia-de-datos, estadística

```
dataset <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
dataset$classe <- factor(dataset$classe, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), labels =c(1,2,3,4,5))

dataset$classe <- as.numeric(dataset$classe)
mreg <- lm(formula = classe ~ ., data = dataset)
summary(mreg)
```

***El código funciona. Son los resultados válidos?*** En regresión lineal con R cuando una variable independiente es categórica, se la cambia por números. Se puede hacer lo mismo cuando es la variable a predecir?
La variable que quiero predecir es la última columna, que tiene el nombre ***classe***. Los valores posibles son A, B, C, D, E.

Soy totalmente nuevo en esta área. Todo consejo es muy apreciado. Los datos están en este GitHub link:

[Data](https://github.com/illyabjazevic/MLcategorialvariable/blob/main/data.csv)

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Ya lo agrego.

Comment: No con una lineal no, en todo caso una regresión logística Ver: https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/choosing-regression-analysis/. Por otro lado entiende que SOes es una comunidad orientada a los temas de programación, la tuya es una pregunta más de teoría estadística (a menos que la reformules de otra manera)  tal vez el lugar más apropiado para hacerla sea  https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: En StackOverflow en Inglés se puede preguntar sobre R. Por eso pensé q este tipo de preguntas estaría OK. Gracias por la idea de regresión logística!

Comment: Sobre R como lenguaje si.. Sobre teoria de estadisticas no. Una cosa es la teoria, y otra programar un lenguaje...

Comment: mira nuesto [tour]... no somos iguales que el sitio en ingles...

Comment: Tú sabes. Todo cambia. Ahora las facultades de computación enseñan R, data science, y machine learning.

Comment: No discutimos eso. Pero Patricio es un experto en el tema. Y lo que te dijo es que tu pregunta no es sobre como hacer eso en R.. si no sobre la teoria de estadistica...

Comment: Q te puedo decir? No estoy de acuerdo. Pero soy una persona respetuosa. Si tienen que cerrar la pregunta, procedan.

Comment: No, para nada.. pero este sitio tiene un ambito, como todos los sitios de la red. En las facultades de sistemas tambien enseñan ingles, contabilidad y otras cosas que estan por fuera del ambito de este sitio. Estamos viendo si podes reescribir tu pregunta para que sea sobre programacion, y no sobre teoria estadistica... Si te parece que habria que modificar el ambito para cubrir estas cosas, sos bienvenido de plantearlo en [meta]

Comment: Comparar contabilidad con data science es una maniobra brillante, pero no procede. En programación es muy común q necesitas entender lo q está pasando para obtener los resultados correctos. Como te dije antes, si eres moderador, haz lo que consideres oportuno. Siempre pregunto en el sitio de Inglés. Supongo que puedo volver allá, si no hay más alternativa. Por cierto... cambié la pregunta.

Comment: Yo soy moderador electo. Pero no tengo ni la primera ni la ultima palabra sobre nada. Y no, no voy a cerrar una pregunta, primero porque no tiene ni un voto de cierre. Segundo porque con las modificaciones la pregunta va mejor, aunque preguntar si los resultados son validos, no seria una pregunta valida (basta con poner en un comentario si o no). En tal caso, podrias explicar porque pensas que son validos, y que alguien explique si eso es correcto, pero siempre sobre el lenguaje, no sobre la explicacion teorica de estadistica. Para eso, hay otro sitio...

Comment: Te felicito. Voy a seguir tu consejo. Aunque recuerda q mi pregunta es q si son válidos. Eso es lo que estoy tratando de descubrir. También trato de descubrir que si no son válidos, cuál es la alternativa. También voy a publicar la pregunta en el sitio de estadística que ustedes me han sugerido.

Comment: Igual ustedes me han dado muchas ideas. Estoy agradecido.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, hoy por hoy matemática y ciencias de la computación van  de la mano como nunca. Tal vez es algo que como comunidad deberíamos reevaluar, sin embargo hay cierto consenso en circunscribir la temática de SOes  a la programación en sí y no a los temas puntuales de dominio. Recuerda también que con tu reputación puedes acceder al [chat] un ámbito mucho menos estructurado.

Comment: Sé que quzás sea fuera de tema, pero por este tipo de casos creo que sería muy importante tener es.stats.stackexchange.com . La pregunta de @Beginner es interesantísima y una buena respuesta podrías servir de mucho a toda la comunidad. Es debatible si es sobre R, personalmente creo que sí en tanto contempla el resultado de una función.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. En mi opinión dividir los sitios no es buena idea. Ya por eso existen las etiquetas. Además hemos entrado en la era del multidomain. Todo se está integrando.

Comment: @Beginner no es asi en esta red. Aca se divide y se especifican comunidades.

Comment: Coincido con @gbianchi. Además cada comunidad requiere herramientas específicas, por ejemplo, para estadística ayuda mucho tener MathJax para escribir ecuaciones, en SO buenas herramientas para presentar y editar código o gráficos. La etiqueta R es bastante particular porque es un lenguaje de dominio específico, pero lo ideal sería dejar aquí las preguntas sobre programación y migrar a otro ámbito las que son de estadística propiamente dicha. Varios seguiríamos ambas etiquetas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a enfocar la respuesta en ¿Por qué R da un resultado "valido" cuando la teoría estadística indica que la aproximación es incorrecta?

Creo que es relevante tomando como punto de partida que R es un lenguaje de programación de dominio específico y que todavía es apropiado entenderlo como un lenguaje hecho por estadísticos para estadísticos, aunque ya haga muchas cosas más.

## ¿Por qué obtienes un output en lugar de un mensaje de error?

Porque la función `lm()` solo evalúa si lo que defines como *y* en tu fórmula pertenece a la clase `numeric`. Si es así procede al ajuste del modelo, ya que matemáticamente es posible resolverlo. `lm()` no tiene forma de saber de dónde salieron esos números y si están cumpliendo o no los supuestos de un modelo lineal.

En cambio si *y* es de la clase factor y usas `lm()` obtendrás un error. ¿Por qué? Porque en ese caso `lm()` tiene información para identificar que se está violando uno de los supuestos de los modelos lineales. Quienes crearon la función `lm()` (Chambers en S adaptada a R por Ihaka) son estadísticos y entonces les preocupa más la consistencia en la estimación de los errores estándar, que es muy vulnerable a las violaciones de supuestos, que la capacidad predictiva de un modelo.

## ¿Es válido el resultado en términos estadísticos?

En tu caso definitivamente no y no hay manera de que lo sea. El problema es que al asignar números a tus categorías (tal que A=1 ... D=5) introduces, de pasada, una magnitud: 1 es la mitad de 2, 4 el doble que 2, etc. El modelo lineal que ajusta `lm()` **va** a usar esa información, porque lo que estima es E(y|x) y asume que la expectativa de *y* es la media de *y*. Y cuando se calcula una media se consideran las magnitudes (sum(x)/n). Ahora bien, si no puedes afirmar que A es la mitad que B y que E es el doble que B entonces los resultados no tienen sentido matemático ni sustantivo.

Hay un caso especial que es diferente al que planteas y es el de *y* dicotómica. Si *y* admite solo dos categorías (digamos: Sí o No) entonces puedes codificarlas como `Sí = 0` y `No = 1`. La clave es que la media aritmética de una variable así codificada es la proporción de *y=1*, ya que cuando haces la sumatoria para la media estás sumando presencia (1) y ausencia (0). En ese caso lo que obtienes es algo que se llama Modelo de Probabilidad Lineal.

Desde el punto de vista **estadístico**, donde la preocupación principal es la estimación de los errores estándar para hacer inferencia estadística este tipo de modelos no tiene mucho sentido y por eso se recomienda usar modelos logit.

Desde un punto de vista de ciencia de datos/machine learning/**modelado predictivo** la estimación de los errores estándar asociados a cada parámetro es mucho menos importante que el error promedio de clasificación en datos futuros (predicción). Entonces si un modelo de probabilidad lineal da buenas predicciones, adelante. Nada te impide que lo uses si en tu métrica de evaluación del modelo anda bien.

En el caso que presentas, sin embargo, esto no funcionaría, por lo dicho sobre las magnitudes implícitas en los números. Una alternativa sería un modelo logit multinomial. En R los implementa la librería `nnet` y `mlogit`.

Comment: Gracias! Genial respuesta!